# Dismiss pickerView and open the corresponding one when a user taps on a different textField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uipickerview

I have mutliple textFields in a view that have there input view set to a pickerView, however depending on the textField there is a different amount of rows of selection that should appear. This works fine when you click outside the picker view and then click on the next textField but causes a crash when you just click on the next textField (This is because the pickerView does not change and so the index becomes out of range). Thanks for the help!

To dismiss the pickerView whenever tapped outside (does not do anything if another textField is tapped):

```
self.view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self.view, action: #selector(UIView.endEditing(_:))))
```

What I mean by when I say different textFields show different amount of rows:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        if ticketOneTextField.isFirstResponder == true {
            if shownEvent?.ticketTypeOnePrice == "0.00" {
                return 2
            } else {
                return 11
            }
        } else if ticketTwoTextField.isFirstResponder == true {
            if shownEvent?.ticketTypeTwoPrice == "0.00" {
                return 2
            } else {
                return 11
            }
        } else if ticketThreeTextField.isFirstResponder == true {
            if shownEvent?.ticketTypeThreePrice == "0.00" {
                return 2
            } else {
                return 11
            }
        } else {
            return 2
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add in viewDidLoad()

when a user starts editing below function is called.

```
textField.addTarget(self, action:#selector(textDidBeginEditing(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidBegin)
```

Then implement this:

```
    func textDidBeginEditing(sender:UITextField) -> Void
    {
       if sender == ticketOneTextField {
             //show pickerview
       } 
       else if sender == ticketOneTextField {
             //show pickerview
       } 
       else if sender == ticketOneTextField {
             //show pickerview
       } 
}

// this pickerview delegate is called when user selects a row.
     optional func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
          //after user selects the value end the editing
          self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
```